# Triviality of holomorphic vector bundles over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology, holomorphic-bundles

Let $E\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic vector bundle.
I found two proofs that $E$ is trivial: one follows from Oka-Grauer principle (Theorem 5.3.1 in F. Forstneric, *Stein Manifolds and Holomorphic Mappings*), which holds for contractible Stein manifolds and the other one can be found in O. Forster, *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*, and applies to non-compact Riemann Surfaces.

Both these arguments are highly nontrivial, and I thought that in the special case of $\mathbb{C}$ there might be a simpler proof. For example, trying to specialize the second proof above, one finds that the case of $\mathbb{C}$ is implied by proving one of the following:

1. $H^0(\mathbb{C},\mathcal{M}(E))\neq 0$, i.e. $E$ has a non-zero meromorphic section;
2. $\operatorname{dim} H^1(\mathbb{C},\mathcal{O}(E))<\infty$.

Although I find them likely to be true, I was not able to prove any of the two. So, the question is:

> Is there an easy proof of either 1. or 2. above? More generally, is there an easier proof than the two arguments above in the case of $\mathbb{C}$?